# What is the name of the file that has the greatest average I/O time for an individual transaction (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, io

I assume the answer is going to be some sort of calculation on a v$ file, but I don't know what constitutes an I/O time?

My question is: 
What constitutes an I/O time?

Comment: Are you looking for which datafile has the most wait time for a specific SQL statement?  That information may be derivable from DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY.  File wait time also shows up in AWR reports, but I think it's only per snapshot, not per SQL.

Comment: I actually don't understand what is meant by I/O time. Is it a percentage of waits to something?  I know this is probably a silly question, but I just don't understand what the I/O is or how it is calculated. I know that I can find elements in the data dictionary, but I don't know what to look at or for.

Comment: It depends on the context.  Is there a specific source or report that contains a column named "I/O time" that you're asking about?

Comment: Jon, this is a lookup question that is supposed to be answered from one of the views available in the data dictionary. I will go back and try to get some clarification - thanks for your help!